# Problem booting Ubuntu after removing Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

so I've got a system that originally had Windows 8.1 on a regular HDD.  I added an SSD and installed Ubuntu on it.  After getting everything setup (this is my new media server), I decided to just format the drive that had Windows on it so I could use it for extra storage in Ubuntu.  The problem is that the MBR or GRUB must've been on that drive (it's sda, the SSD is sdb) and now it's gone so the computer won't boot.  I've booted up using my Ubuntu 14.04 Live USB and have installed and tried running Boot Repair, but it keeps complaining about some GPT partition and I'll admit, I have no clue what that is.  I can't seem to get this working with any of the automated tools so I'm hoping that someone here will be able to help.  Here's a link to the log that the Boot Repair program gave me, any help will be greatly appreciated. http://paste.ubuntu.com/10666549/

Answer (score 0):

The warnings and errors concerning a corrupt/invalid GPT (GUID partition table) pertain to a 2 GiB drive, so probably neither the hard drive nor the SSD, and can be safely ignored. Unfortunately that doesn't explain why Boot-Repair doesn't fix the boot loader.

To resolve your issue, I recommend a [manual re-installation of Grub](/q/25425), which will be slightly more complicated than depicted in the answers to that question because of logical volume management on your system.

If you don't know what that is or how to deal with it, I recommend that you re-install Ubuntu without logical volume management (LVM), as it is an advanced option and causes more problems than it resolves in simple setups managed by inexperienced administrators.

Answer (score 0):

My recommended solution is:

1. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
2. Prepare a boot medium from this download.
3. If it's not already disabled, [disable Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) (You can re-enable it later, if you like, although you'll probably need to jump through some extra hoops to do so.)
4. Boot rEFInd. You should see at least one option to boot Linux.
5. Boot Linux from rEFInd.
6. Install rEFInd to your hard disk by using the Debian package or PPA referred to on the rEFInd downloads page referenced earlier.

If everything goes right, rEFInd will now be your default boot program and it will boot Ubuntu correctly. You can forget about GRUB at this point.

Alternatively, you can manually install GRUB in the final step rather than install rEFInd. This will involve running the `grub-install` command, and perhaps `update-grub` to generate a fresh configuration file, but I don't recall the precise syntax you'd need to use.