# Can't boot into Windows 8.1 from Grub menu on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

My computer specs -

- 2GB RAM,
- Intel Core2Duo @ 2.7 GHz,
- 250 GB HDD.

I've Windows 8.1 in partition C:\ and when installing UBUNTU 14.04 LTS, I chose the option "something else" and selected another partition with 40 GB for Ubuntu.

I formatted it with EXT4 format and selected an unallocated space of 2 GB as swap area, I then clicked install now option.

Ubuntu got installed, and everything was fine on Ubuntu, the grub menu too, was perfect. But the only problem was, when I choose the option "Windows 8.1 loader" the screen turns purple (it remains the in the background color of Grub menu), and it sits there for hours. I've to restart (using power button on CPU!), but still UBUNTU working perfectly, but windows isn't.

I've reinstalled UBUNTU thrice, but the same error happens again! Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `update-grub` , if not open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)  and type `sudo update-grub`
and restart. If the issue is still there try clearing cmos. ( with jumper resetting )

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's critical to know if you're booting in BIOS mode or in EFI mode. Boot to Linux and type the following commands (shown here with possible outputs):

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print | grep Table
Partition Table: gpt
$ ls /sys/firmware/
acpi  efi  memmap
```

The first command reveals (by proxy) your Windows boot mode. (Note that this assumes you've got one disk, `/dev/sda`. If you've got two or more disks, you must issue that command against the Windows boot disk.) Windows boots from GPT disks *only* in EFI/UEFI mode, and from MBR disks (which `parted` identifies as being of type `msdos`) *only* in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.

The second command shows the presence of a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi` when Ubuntu is booted in EFI mode, and the absence of such a directory when the system is booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.

This example shows a GPT disk (indicative of an EFI-mode install of Windows, if it were present on this computer) and an EFI-mode boot of Linux.

Because there are two possibilities for both options, there are four possibilities in total:

- Both installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode: In this case, running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) might fix your problem, although I can't make any promises about that.
- Both installed in EFI/UEFI mode: My suspicion is that you're running into [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464) long-standing bug. Try [disabling Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) or installing [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)
- Windows installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, Ubuntu in EFI mode: Install a BIOS-mode version of GRUB to replace the EFI-mode version; or install rEFInd and edit its `refind.conf` file to add `hdbios` to the `scanfor` options. (This combination of boot modes is pretty rare except on Macs.)
- Windows installed in EFI/UEFI mode, Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode: Install your choice of [EFI boot loader for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) Boot Repair can usually set up GRUB correctly, but be sure to do this *in EFI mode*; or installing rEFInd will also usually work -- but it's best to do this in EFI mode. See my answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600549/problem-booting-ubuntu-after-removing-windows/600680#600680) for more detail on this possibility.

Comment: Systems with core2 duo were before UEFI. And with 2GB of RAM it just about has to be an older system. More likely the issue is that the always on hibernation or Windows Fast Startup was left on. Grub only boots working Windows and fast startup interferes with that. Probable have to reinstall a Windows boot loader to boot in BIOS mode, turn off the fast startup in Windows and then restore grub2's boot loader to MBR.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the Core2 Duo series lasted from 2006 to 2008. UEFI became *common* on PCs starting in mid-2011, but it was available on some models well before then. I've got an Intel DG43NB motherboard from 2008 that uses UEFI. There are also Core2 Duo (and even Core Duo) Macs from that period that used EFI. Thus, checking the boot mode even on older systems makes sense.